# Selectively disabling gvfsd-cdda in Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian, audio-cd, ripping, eject

Is there a way to selectively disable `gvfsd-cdda` on Debian Squeeze?

Since I updated my machine to Squeeze `grip` can no longer eject a CD, which interferes with ripping. I traced it back to `gvfsd-cdda`, but found no preference or configuration to disable it. I can't uninstall package `gvfs-backends` either, because it is required by `gnome-core`.

I did find `/usr/share/mounts/cdda.mount`, but disabling that feels like an ugly hack that will be overwritten on the next update of the package.

Comment: If you use k3b, it should pop up the dialog with an option to kill the process.  It's fine to do so because it'll start up next time you eject/load a cd to automount it.  You can always just run `pkill gvfsd-cdda` manually.  Or you could add a context menu option to the `.desktop` file for `grip`.  [An example of how to do this for k3b can be found here](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntuusers.de%2FK3b%23gvfsd-cdda-Beenden-Dialog-vor-dem-Auslesen-einer-Audio-CD-unter-GNOME).  You can adapt it by finding the appropriate `grip.desktop` file.

Comment: `find /usr/share/applications/ -iname '*grip*.desktop'` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if there's a way to fix or cleanly disable `gvfsd-cdda`, but you can move it out of the way without running into trouble with the package manager.

Debian (and more generally any distribution using `dpkg`) has a generic mechanism for providing your own version of a file that's normally under the package manager's control. If you find you must change `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-cdda` or `/usr/share/mounts/cdda.mount`, use `dpkg-divert` so that the package's version will be diverted to a different file name:

```
dpkg-divert --add --local --rename --divert /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-cdda.debian /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-cdda
ln -s /bin/true /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-cdda
```

or perhaps

```
dpkg-divert --add --local --rename --divert /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/cdda.mount.debian /usr/share/gvfs/mounts/cdda.mount
```

Comment: This doesn't work real well, though, as you'll get a dialog box after about 5 minutes from dbus complaining that "gvfsd-cdda didn't respond".  Less annoying than having sound-juicer leap up in your face every time, but still a pain.

Comment: @womble: Did you try just doing the first step (diverting `gvfsd-cdda`) and not the second, and then perhaps restarting dbus? Or diverting `/usr/share/gvfs/mounts/cdda.mount` instead (and perhaps restarting Gnome)?

Comment: It's your answer, not mine.  Just saying that your answer, as written, isn't a good solution.